# How do I get a Google N-Gram plot with a logarithmic axis?

Tags: google-ngram-viewer

I have an N-Gram plot where the frequencies span several orders of magnitude and are thus some relevant results are not really readable on a linear scale. I am aware that I can multiply some lines with a constant, but that makes the data I want to present overly complicated. Using a [logarithmic scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logscale) for the frequencies would however solve my problem.

This feature does not seem to be directly available, but this issue is also not that important to me that I would download the raw data and analyse it myself. So my question is: **Is there an easy way to obtain a logarithmic frequency axis for a Google Ngram?**

A possible solution would for example involve somehow obtaining the data shown in my particular plot (which I could then plot logarithmically myself).

Comment: Any luck on this? I need log for [this plot](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70834/what-are-the-previous-uses-of-false-justifications-for-invasions-used-by-russia?noredirect=1#comment293649_70834).